# angularjs: how to add caching to resource object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

To add caching inside http is pretty straight forward. ( by passing cache=true )

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) has Cache option.

How do I add similar functionality in $resource in angularjs ?

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/K_PoqLcOiuo/OkDpVrz7HsEJ

Comment: Well, that does not solve the problem, "implement it yourself" it not what he and me are looking for

Comment: The only answer right now is "implement it yourself" until the next version of angular.  You can use this implementation which is in a PR: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1045

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Since 1.1.2 ([commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/af89daf4641f57b92be6c1f3635f5a3237f20c71)), all the $httpConfig options are directly exposed in $resource action objects:

```
return {
  Things: $resource('url/to/:thing', {}, {
    list : {
      method : 'GET',
      cache : true
    }
  })
 };
```

Comment: Maybe you can open a new question and provide an example?

Comment: This isn't a very good answer. The current stable version of AngularJS is 1.0.7 and there are some workplaces that use older versions. How do we get around this if we aren't using 1.1.2?

Comment: You could extract the relevant changes from the $resource files (which is not part of the core), and patch it into the stable branch. Since the 1.1.x branch is in my experience very stable, I can recommend using it. Anyway, it is one possible solution to the problem, not the definite answer.

Answer (score 56):

Implementing your own cache in AngularJs is quite easy. Just use [$cacheFactory](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24cacheFactory):

```
app.factory('myService', function($resource, $cacheFactory) {
   var cache = $cacheFactory('myService');
   var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});

   return {
      getResource: function(userId) {
         var user = cache.get(userId);
         if (!user) {
            user = User.get({userId:userId});
            cache.put(userId, user);   
         }
         return user;
      }
   };
});
```

Comment: Actually, $resource now has built-in cache support. No need to keep doing it manually.

Answer (score 24):

As the docs state, [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) has built-in support for [$cacheFactory](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory). You can pass it in via the `cache` property of each action:

> `cache` – `{boolean|Cache}` – If `true`, a default `$http` cache will be used to cache the `GET` request, otherwise if a cache instance built with `$cacheFactory`, this cache will be used for caching.

Example usage:

```
app.factory('Todos', function($resource, $cacheFactory) {
    var todosCache = $cacheFactory('Todos');
    return $resource(apiBaseUrl + '/todos/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
        'get': { method:'GET', cache: todosCache},
        'query': { method:'GET', cache: todosCache, isArray:true }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should pass a Cache instance (built with $cacheFactory) not the $cacheFactory itself.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't seem to be mentioned here but you can also overwrite the default methods.

```
app.factory("List", ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource("./lists/:path/:action.json", {}, {
        get: {
            method: "GET",
            cache: true
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: The problem with `cache: true` is that it only caches GET requests. If you want to cache HEAD requests,  you're out of luck.

Answer (score 6):

You can also set default cache for $http and thus for $resource which is based on it.

My settings with the excellent [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache) allowing LocalStorage and compliant with $cacheFactory:

```
app.run(function($http, DSCacheFactory) {

    DSCacheFactory('defaultCache', {
        deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive',
        storageMode: 'localStorage' 
    });

    $http.defaults.cache = DSCacheFactory.get('defaultCache');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the angular-resource source indicates that triggering caching isn't possible with the way it is currently written.

Here's the request object from the source:

```
$http({
    method: action.method,
    url: route.url(extend({}, extractParams(data), action.params || {}, params)),
    data: data
 }).then(...)
```

There are a few potential ways to deal with this.

First, you could cache locally using client-side persistence.  I use [amplify.store](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/) with wrapper (b/c I don't really like the API syntax).  There are a variety other storage solutions depending on what you're looking for and what browser's your targeting.  Quite a few people use [lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) as well.

You can then stringify and store your models locally and update them based on whatever rules or time limits you desire.

Another solution is to simply modify angular resource to accept the parameters you're looking for. This could be as simple (simply add an additional argument to $resource) or complex as you need it to be.

e.g.

```
function ResourceFactory(url, paramDefaults, actions, cache) {
   ...
   var cache = cache != null ? cache : false; // Set default to false
   $http({
        method: action.method,
        url: route.url(extend({}, extractParams(data), action.params || {}, params)),
        data: data,
        cache: cache
    }).then(...)       
}
```

Finally, depending on you requirements, it might be significantly easier to simply create your own resource, using angular.factory to create a service.  One of the advantages of ngResource is that is does all of the string interpolation work for you when translating parameters.  However, you can certainly barrow this logic for parsing if you need it, or write your own based on the models you're using.

Comment: What about jsstorage, would you use it against amplify.store?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but looking at the syntax and feature set, I like it better than Amplify.  It's been awhile since I looked at any of these, since I haven't been writing code for old browsers recently (and thus just use a lightweight localStorage wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this really well thought out module called angular-cached-resource that will do the job for you. https://github.com/goodeggs/angular-cached-resource

It is a drop in replacement for $resource, with added functionality of cache management using localStorage. If your browser doesnt support local storage, you will not get any caching benefit. Here's an example of how you can use it:

**The old way using $resource:**

```
var Entry = $resource('/entries/:slug', {slug: '@slug'});

var announcement = new Entry();
announcement.slug = 'announcing-angular-cached-resource';
announcement.title = 'Announcing Angular Cached Resource';
announcement.body = 'Here is why Angular Cached Resource is awesome!';

announcement.$save(function() {
  alert('Saved announcement.');
});
```

**The new way using $cachedResource:**

```
var Entry = $cachedResource('entries', '/entries/:slug', {slug: '@slug'});

var announcement = new Entry();
announcement.slug = 'announcing-angular-cached-resource';
announcement.title = 'Announcing Angular Cached Resource';
announcement.body = 'Here is why Angular Cached Resource is awesome!';

announcement.$save(function() {
  alert('Saved announcement.');
});
```

The only differences in the code are:

1. Use $cachedResource instead of $resource
2. Provide a "key" (`entries`in the example above) so that you can
   refer to it even between page refreshes or reloads. These entries
   persist since out of the box it uses localStorage.

A detailed tutorial is available here: https://github.com/goodeggs/bites/blob/master/src/documents/open_source/2014-04-24-angular-cached-resource.md

Also note Angular 2.0 may support something like this out of the box: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DMacL7iwjSMPP0ytZfugpU4v0PWUK0BT6lhyaVEmlBQ/edit

Answer (score 0):

I'm using angular-resource 1.5.5 and set my code up the following way:

#### Summary

Set *action* as **query**, and since the "query" action is expecting a response deserialized as an array, isArray will need to be explicitly set to true. My understanding is by default ngResource actions expect objects except query.
[See here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg)

**Controller**

```
angular.module("app")
    .controller('myCtrl',['$scope','myService',function($scope, myService) {
        $scope.myData= myService.myResource.query();
    }]);
```

**Service**

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('myService',['$resource',function($resource){
        var baseUrl = 'http://www.MyExample.com/';
        return{
            myResource:$resource(baseURL + '/myEndpoint/:id', {id:'@id'},{
                'query':{
                    method:'GET',
                    cache:'true',
                    isArray:true
                }}),
        }
    }]);
```