# Why isn't angularjs caching my request to the github api?

Tags: caching, angularjs, jsonp, github-api

I have a small repo factory service that I am using in my controller:

My Controller:

```
angular.module('repoApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $repoService) {
    $scope.repos = $repoService.getRepos();
  });
```

My Factory:

```
angular.module('repoApp')
  .factory('$repoService', function ($http) {
    var repos =
      // $http.defaults.headers['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Sat, 01 Jun 2013 1:31:30 GMT';
      $http.jsonp('https://api.github.com/repos/mojombo/jekyll/issues?state=closed&callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
      {
        cache: true
      }
    );
    // Public API here
    return {
      getRepos: function () {
        return repos.then(function(repoData) {
          return repoData.data.data;
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

This works fine - I get back the results but every time the browser refreshes, I end up getting a 200 response instead of a 304. What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried using `JSON_SINGLE_CALLBACK` as mentioned in [this closed issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1548).

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually using the GitHub method of checking for a modified set of issues. You have it commented out but I'm not sure the list of issues actually return (or work with) the `Last-Modified`/`If-Modified-Since` headers. It should return an `ETag` header which you can then send back using `If-None-Match`. Otherwise, I might guess that angular is only going to cache for the single page load and that if you added a way of testing (without refreshing the page in the browser) this, e.g., a button to re-issue this request, you might see angular cache the request.

Then again you should check the documentation to see if you should be expecting a 200 (the original response) or a 304 (a faked response). You should also check the headers on the response to see if your ratelimit changes.

Comment: I do not know Angular that well but I read some other questions for you and read their documentation for you. Here's a question that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225475/angularjs-how-to-add-caching-to-resource-object (read all of the answers) and their documentation for how to perform caching (although they seem to suggest using `$resource` instead of `$http`): http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http